# Aptana Studio 3.2 with ruby1.9.3 and cldwalker/debugger

Tags: ruby-on-rails, debugging, aptana

I can't get debug to work in Aptana Studio 3.2 with ruby 1.9.3p0 and cldwalker/debugger.

If i have ruby-debug installed it outputs this error:

/usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:59:in `require': /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/ruby-debug-base19-0.11.25/lib/ruby_debug.so: undefined symbol: ruby_current_thread - /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/ruby-debug-base19-0.11.25/lib/ruby_debug.so (LoadError)

If I don't have it, nothing happens when debug button is clicked.

Running debugger(rails server --debugger) from terminal works fine, so this seems to me, like AS3 have somewhere ruby-debug setting hardcoded in.

Is it possible to debug apps with cldwalker/debugger?

Thanks in advance.